# ASIHTTPRequest download is writing JSON error to zip

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I have a method for downloading a file as file_name.zip to the documents directory. However, if I receive an error, such as 'file does not exist', the library is writing the JSON payload to file_name.zip.

How do we check for JSON error in `requestFinished:`?

responseString or responseData is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to check the `request.responseStatusCode` and check against a 404 error. But honestly you should look into AFNetworking. ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported and AFNetworking has success/failure blocks.

Comment: I will certainly check out that library. The status code is always 200. But I receive a JSON payload with an error such as, invalid credentials or file does not exist. Therefore status is still 200 although no file was returned.

Comment: Swapped out library, using AFNetworking, seems to be working. Thanks for the suggestion.